# Properly use single and double quatation in PHP

Tags: php

I have my PHP code like below and its work fine

```
<tr onclick="window.location='../info/<?php echo $ouid;?>';" class="tbl_rated_orders">
```

Now I am loading more data on press load more button via ajax

so I am trying like this

```
$tableData.= '<tr class="tbl_rated_orders_buyer" onclick="window.location='.'"../info/'.$ouid.';">
                                    
                                        <td>'.$date_rated.'</td>
                                        <td><img src="../../global_assets/uploads/users/'.$image.'" width="35" class="rounded-pill" alt="">
                                        <span class="ml-2">'.$rated_row["full_name"].'</span>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                        <td>'.$cancelled_by_txt.'</td>
                                        <td><i class="icon-paperplane text-dark mr-1"></i>'.$str1.'</td>
                                    </tr>';
```

But now tr html code looks like this

```
<tr class="tbl_rated_orders_buyer" onclick="window.location=" ..="" info="" zxp2ibhfnu;"="">
```

so its not correct code for window location, its need like this

```
<tr onclick="window.location='../info/RQ5KWBIY6M';" class="tbl_cancelled_orders">
```

I am new in PHP and trying from half hour to make it working but not getting idea how I can do it, Let me know if anyone here can help me for do the same.
Thanks!

Comment: I would be using `sprintf()` instead of all that concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape some single quotes for the single quotes used in the javascript in the onclick attribute.

```
$ouid = "asd0f8a08f0";
$date_rated = "12/03/2021";
$image = "north_pole.jpg";
$rated_row["full_name"] = "Mighty Mouse";
$cancelled_by_txt = "grinch";
$str1 = "Paper Plane";
$tableData = "";

$tableData.= '<tr class="tbl_rated_orders_buyer" onclick="window.location='.'\'../info/'.$ouid.';\'">
                                    
                                        <td>'.$date_rated.'</td>
                                        <td><img src="../../global_assets/uploads/users/'.$image.'" width="35" class="rounded-pill" alt="">
                                        <span class="ml-2">'.$rated_row["full_name"].'</span>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                        <td>'.$cancelled_by_txt.'</td>
                                        <td><i class="icon-paperplane text-dark mr-1"></i>'.$str1.'</td>
                                    </tr>';
```

Output:

```
<tr class="tbl_rated_orders_buyer" onclick="window.location='../info/asd0f8a08f0;'">
                                
                                    <td>12/03/2021</td>
                                    <td><img src="../../global_assets/uploads/users/north_pole.jpg" width="35" class="rounded-pill" alt="">
                                    <span class="ml-2">Mighty Mouse</span>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    <td>grinch</td>
                                    <td><i class="icon-paperplane text-dark mr-1"></i>Paper Plane</td>
```